# MySQL, present seconds in mm:ss format

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there an easy way to convert seconds to an mm:ss format (minutes and seconds)? I'm doing e.g.

```
select colA,ROUND(AVG(seconds)) from table group by colA.
```

I'd like to show this in an mm:ss format  (*note that this is not what the MySQL SEC_TO_TIME does, it always gives you the HH part as well*)

if seconds is 90, i'd like "1:30", or "01:30" would be ok too. 
If seconds is 3602 , either of "60:02" or "01:00:02" would be fine, but truncating off the hour to "00:02" would not be..

Comment: how is your value stored in database, is it time stamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way :-

```
mysql> set @sec:= 3602;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select concat( lpad(floor(@sec/60), 2, 0), ':', lpad((@sec%60), 2, 0));
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| concat( lpad(floor(3602/60), 2, 0), ':', lpad((3602 % 60), 2, 0)) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 60:02                                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `floor` to find the hours, and `mod` to find the minutes:

```
select  concat(floor(column_with_seconds/60), 
        ':',
        mod(column_with_seconds,60))
```

[Working example at SqlLize.](http://www.sqlize.com/j3TaNC67Zc)